# How to include one specific row from another table with LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a database with these two tables: `Customer` and `CustomerStatus`. `CustomerStatus` is a so called readonly table. All changes to a customer's status result in an INSERT into that table. The current customer status is locatable via `CustomerStatus.StatusTimestamp`.

Now I'm looking for a LINQ to entities query that loads all Customers together with their current status. Something like

`.Include("CustomerStatus.OrderByDescending(StatusTimestamp).FirstOrDefault()")`.

I haven't found a proper way with with EF 4.0.

My current workaround is very ugly and uses 2 steps:

step 1: LINQ query that loads all status (in the business/data layer):

`var r = from c in db.Customers.Include("CustomerStatus")
        select c;`

step 2: take the suitable status from each customer in the GUI (in a loop in a MVC3 view):

`c.CustomerStatus.OrderByDescending(i => i.StatusTimestamp).FirstOrDefault()`

Any idea how this can be done directly in one step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF is more powerful than you give it credit for. One of the things it can do is project to complex types *within an `IQueryable`* (ie, in one database hit). This should work:

```
var data = 
    from c in db.Customers
    select new { 
        Customer = c, 
        LastStatus = c.CustomerStatus  // assuming navigation property set up right
                      .OrderByDescending(s => s.StatusTimestamp)
                      .FirstOrDefault()
    };
```

Now `data` is an `IQueryable<anonymous_type>`, and each item has a `Customer` property giving the customer, and a `LastStatus` giving the latest-timestamped status, or `null` if there aren't any status records for the customer.

You can use a named type here too, it's just quicker for me to type it this way :).

Comment: Works fine. Thanks!
Actually I still do it in 3 steps, but all in the BLL now:
1: `var q = ...`.
2: `var l = q.ToList()` (to force lazy load the status).
3: `return l.Select(i => i.Customer)` (to still return an IEnumerable<Customer>, and not an anonymous type).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your schema looks like but what about

```
var query = from c in db.Customers 
            join CustomerStatus s on c.StatusTimestamp = s.StatusTimestamp
            order by s.StatusTimestamp
            select c;
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this??

```
   var r = (from c in db.Customers.Include("CustomerStatus")
            where c.CustomerStatus.OrderByDescending(i => i.StatusTimestamp)
            select c).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Can you comment on why this is not useful?

Comment: But that's just a pseudocode mate. How could I know what is Customers and CustomerStatus class holds?

Comment: Never mind the identifiers, what is going on with that `where` clause? Is that what `where` clauses look like?