# How to select a last row from Include

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using EF 7 and MVC 5 to create a web application. I need to select all header rows from my database.

These rows will use a class like below:

```
public class Log_Header
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string App_Name { get; set; }
    public string App_Url { get; set; }
    public string Submitted_By { get; set; }
    public string App_Contact { get; set; }
    public string App_Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Log_Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I have a collection of `Log_Details`.

The statement I am using is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Log_Header> getLogHeaders()
{
     return _context.LogHeader.Include(t => t.Details).ToList();
}
```

Now comes the problem I am having, I only need the last row (max id row) from `Details` but I cannot find a way to do this. I have tried a few ways with no luck, thought it would look similar to this:

```
_context.LogHeader.Include(t => t.Details.Last()).ToList();
```

The error I keep getting is:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Remotion.Linq.Clauses.Expressions.SubQueryExpression' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.

If anyone has any clue please leave a comment or answer, please remember this is using EF 7.

Comment: Include is expecting the path to a navigation property, not an actual member. I do believe your best bet is lazy loading the necessary object, instead of eagerly loading the tree.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Thank you for your reply. I believe EF 7 does not currently support lazy loading... So that's a bit of a problem.

Comment: did u try _context.LogHeader.Include(t => t.Details.LastOrDefault()).ToList();

Comment: @janina Yes, I get the same error. Also `Details` will always have a value.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329285/how-to-include-one-specific-row-from-another-table-with-linq-to-entities) example? maybe you can use left join @furkick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF does not support inlcuding only the First/Last/Whatever row.
EF only supports including a whole Table (i.e. it does a JOIN).
Therefore you will always get `Log_Header.Count() * Log_Detail().Count()` rows.
This will cost you a ton of performance.

Better load the Data in 2 round trips to the database.
Even better: do them in parallel and async.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Log_Header>> GetHeaderWithLastDetailAsync()
{
    var headerTask = GetLogHeadersAsync();
    var detailTask = GetLastDetailByHeaderIdAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(headerTask, detailTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var header = headerTask.Result;
    var detail = detailTask.Result;

    foreach(var h in header)
    {
        Log_Detail d;
        if(detail.TryGetValue(h.Id, out d)
            h.Details.Add(d);
    }
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Log_Header>> GetLogHeadersAsync()
{
    using(var context = new MyContext())
    {
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        return await context.LogHeader.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public async Task<IDictionary<int, Log_Detail>> GetLastDetailByHeaderIdAsync()
{
    using(var context = new MyContext())
    {
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        return await context.LogDetail.ToDictionaryAsync(d => d.HeaderId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```